# How can this printf statement be executed by the C compiler?

Tags: c++, c

I am confused about how the `printf` statement is working in this program? I want to know the way of executing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a=5;
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",a++,++a,++a,1);
    printf("%d",a);
    //printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will invoke **undefined behavior**. Statement

```
 printf("%d %d %d %d\n",a++,++a,++a,1);
```

trying to modify `a` thrice between two sequence point.